# Array errors in C Language

Tags: c, arrays

When i run this code for selection 2 in the menu, after entering the trn number the program displays the investment type without the 1st letter and doesn't do the calculation assigned to it. Also for selection 3 the program runs continuously after selecting option 3 in the menu

```
    switch(option)
    {
    case 1:
        system("cls");
        printf(" How many clients are to be signed up ? \n");
            scanf(" %d",&num);
            system("cls");
            for(i=0;i<num;i++)
            {
                printf("\n Investment Type Available");
                printf("\n 1. Bonds 2. Stocks   3. MutualFund");
                printf("\n ");
                printf(" Enter the clients data \n");
                printf(" TRN              : ");
                scanf(" %s",&trn[i]);
                printf("\n Investment Type  : ");
                scanf(" %s",&p_type[i]);
                printf("\n Amount Investing : ");
                scanf(" %lf",&i_amount[i]);
                system("cls");
                t_amount=t_amount+i_amount[i];
            }
            getch();
            goto Menu;
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("\n Enter clients TRN : ");
        scanf("%s",&trn[i]);
        if(strcmp(trn[i],trn[i])==0)
        {
            printf("\n Investment type for this client : %s",&p_type[i]);

        }
        else
        {
            printf("No record found for this client");
            getch();
            return 0;
        }
        printf("\n TRN                     : %s",&trn[i]);
        printf("\n Investment Type         : %s",&p_type[i]);
        printf("\n Interest to be received  : $%0.2lf",s_interest);
        getch();
        goto Menu;
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("Each clients TRN & Investment Type :");
        for(i=0;i<num;i++)
        {
            if(i=num)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
               printf("\n TRN : %s   Investment Type : %s",&trn[i],&p_type[i]);
            }
            if(lowest<i_amount[i])
            {
                lowest=i_amount[i];
            }
        }
        a_amount=t_amount/num;
        printf("The average amount that could be invested per person is : $%0.2lf",&a_amount);
        printf("The client with the least amount to invest ");
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("Exiting system");
        getch();
        return 0;
        break;
    default :
        printf("Invalid selection");
        getch();
        return 0;
    }
}

return 0;
getch();
```

}

Comment: Reduce your code to the minimum required to demonstrate your problem.  Also note that doing `getch()` or `break` after `return` has no effect.

Comment: maybe `char trn[10]` --> `char trn[10][max string length + 1]`

Comment: Your code is littered with problems. 1. `scanf(" %s",&trn[i]);` the second parameter is not a valid buffer for storing a string. It's a pointer to some part of the array but pretty sure that's not what you want. Same for almost all the other places you have `&trn[i]`. 2. `strcmp(trn[i],trn[i])` why comparing something to itself? And in any case `trn[i]` is a single `char` not a string buffer.

Comment: bare with me i am still new to this @kaylum

Comment: I am bearing with you. That's why I'm pointing out your mistakes so that you can fix them. But why did you remove some of the code so that it is no longer complete? As for option 3 this `if(i=num)` should be `if(i==num)`. But in fact, there is no need for that conditional block at all. The `for` loop already has that built into it. At the start of each `for` iteration the check `i<num` is performed and at the end of each `for` loop iteration `i++` is run.

Comment: when is the assignment due?

Comment: @Joshua has a good answer for your question regarding the missing character, and as far as the infinite loop on option 3, I'm guessing it's because it is the only one which doesn't explicitly either `return` from the function or `goto`. As mentioned, there are several mistakes in your code, and we would be happy to help, but sometimes we don't really know where to begin or what's going on. The comments by @kaylum are correct but there is a lot to discuss here. Perhaps some additional concrete questions would help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to use scanf() for reading input from the keyboard. That way lies madness. Change all scanf() calls to fgets() and correct the necessary.

Especially the horror of mixing scanf() with getch(). That's undefined due to how buffering works.

Comment: He is right. Although using `getch()` is a common beginner technique to control program flow execution, many don't realize it is actually reading some characters and may cause some undefined behaviors. Since you are missing a character, I would definitely consider this.